# AMC Problem Help 12B 2010

Tags: contest-math

> A geometric sequence $(a_n)$  has $a_1=\sin x$, $a_2=\cos x$ , and $a_3=\tan x$  for some real number $x$. For what value of $n$ does $a_n=1+\cos x$?

The AMC website has a solution to this, and I wish I could post that here. I would like to know how else this could be solved, not using their solution process.

The solution they used was to show $\cos^3 x=\sin^2 x$ and then multiply by the common ratio $\cos x/\sin x$ until $$a_8= \frac 1 {\cos^2 x}$$ is reached. They then, after rewriting $\sin^2 x$ with cosine squared, proceeded to show that $$\frac 1{\cos^2 x}=1+\cos x$$

Is there any other method? Someone mentioned finding a geometric series within a geometric series, which I could not produce.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the sequence is geometric, we may write it as 
$$
\sin x, q\,\sin x, q^2\,\sin x, \ldots
$$
Then $q=\cos x/\sin x$. We also know that 
$$
q^2=\frac{\tan x}{\sin x}=\frac1{\cos x}, \ q^3=q\,q^2=\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\,\frac1{\cos x}=\frac1{\sin x}.
$$
So we want $a_n=1+\cos x$, i.e. $q^{n-1}\sin x=1+\cos x$. Then
$$
q^{n-1}=\frac1{\sin x}+\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}=q^3+q.
$$
Cancelling one $q$ we get
$$
q^{n-2}=q^2+1=\frac{\cos^2x}{\sin ^2x}+1=\frac1{\sin^2x}=\frac1{\sin x}\,\frac1{\sin x}=q^3\,q^3=q^6.
$$
So $n=8$.

Comment: Wonderful! I only wish I could think like that. What led you to try that method?

Comment: If you think about it, I just wrote what the geometric progression was, and I started writing the powers of $q$. Then I wrote the equation $a_n=1+\cos x$ using the information I had about the first 3 powers.